# Finding which list (of multiple) a value is in

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several lists of general categories in different columns, with each category title in row 1 and each having several different items in rows below it. Picture for reference:

[image]

On this same worksheet I want to be able to enter any of the items (Pork, Apple, Cheese, etc.) in cell E2 (my lookup value).  What formula can I put in cell F2 to have it return the header of the list that item belongs to (Meat, Fruit, Dairy, etc.)?  With my current understanding of V/HLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH formulas I believe you can only lookup values in a single row or , but here I want to be able to have a lookup array of multiple rows and columns, and have it return the value of the top row of the appropriate column.

Edit:

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
=HLOOKUP(E2,A1:D5,1,FALSE)
=INDEX(A1:D5,1,MATCH(E2,A2:D5,0))
```

I am using Excel 2016

Comment: Please include your own attempt on any of the formulas. It may also be wise to include your version of Excel (e.g: 2016, 2019 or 365 etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `SUMPRODUCT`.

If your lookup value is in `E2` and your formula in `F2`, use this formula:

```
=INDEX(A1:D1,SUMPRODUCT((A2:D5=E2)*COLUMN(A2:D5)))
```

This formula is not an array formula, and doesn't require the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Nice, better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

`=INDEX(A1:D1,,MIN(IF(E2=A2:D5,COLUMN(A:D))))`
Enter the formula with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

`MIN` searches for the first `TRUE` where `E2=A2:D5` and returns in which column `A:D` that was and returns that number for use in your INDEX.